# Bootstrap reordering columns on small Devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have a simple layout with two columns in twitter bootstrap.

On large devices the large colum should be on the left side and the small on the right one. 
But when I view the page on a mobile device with smaller screen and the pages get stacked I would like to have the left colum on top of the right one.

```
Large devices:
----- colum 1 --- colum 2---- small devices:
----- colum 2 -----
----- colum 1 -----
```

My code at the moment is the following:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-9 column">        
    <div class="col-md-3 column">
</div>
```

Comment: In your example, you have column 2 above column 1, whereas in your description, you say you want the left column (i.e., column 1) above the right column (i.e., column 2). Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-md-3 pull-right">field2 - width 3</div>
      <div class="col-md-9 pull-right">field1 - width 9</div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Bootply Demo**](http://www.bootply.com/L87a1pVSiy)

The base approach is ***mobile first***.  You set everything for the smallest screen first and then apply adjustments to the larger screen sizes.

"`pull-right`" on every field will completely reverse the order.

Comment: Thanks for the help. As you said your solution complete reverses the order. But your answer was key to my solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-md-3 pull-right-md ">field2 - width 3</div>
      <div class="col-md-9">field1 - width 9</div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .pull-right-md {
    float: right !important;
  }
}
```

Was exactly what i needed!